# Bash Rename Files Script Not Working

Tags: linux, bash

I have the following script and for some reason it is not working

```
find . -name '*---*' | while read fname3 

do
    new_fname3=`echo $fname3 | tr "---" "-"`

    if [ -e $new_fname3 ]
    then
            echo "File $new_fname3 already exists. Not replacing $fname3"
    else
            echo "Creating new file $new_fname3 to replace $fname3"
            mv "$fname3" $new_fname3
    fi

done
```

However if I use

```
find . -name '*---*' | while read fname3 

do
    new_fname3=`echo $fname3 | tr "-" "_"`

    if [ -e $new_fname3 ]
    then
            echo "File $new_fname3 already exists. Not replacing $fname3"
    else
            echo "Creating new file $new_fname3 to replace $fname3"
            mv "$fname3" $new_fname3
    fi

done
```

The script works but I end up with 3 underscores "*_*" how can I replace the 3 dashes "---" with a single dash?

Thanks,

Comment: In `bash`, you can use `new_fname3=${fname3//---/_}` to modify the file name.

Comment: @chepner This is the cleanest solution, avoiding the need to create a subshell. Put some double quotes around that substitute expression though.

Comment: A single expansion on the right-hand side of an assignment does not undergo word-splitting, so the quotes there would be optional.

Comment: @chepner Okay. Just being paranoid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `man tr`. `tr` will just replace single characters.

Use something like `perl -wpe "s/---/-/"` instead.

Also have a look at `man 1p rename`. It is doing pretty much exactly what you want:

```
rename 's/---/-/' *---*
```

Comment: With `tr -s` you can truncate sequences of the selected characters, though; but in this case, it's better to do it purely in shell.

Comment: Ended up modifying my script to use the rename function. - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to change the `tr` for a `sed` substitution:

`tr '---' '-'` should be changed to `sed -e 's/---/-/g`

As an example of the difference:

```
$ echo "a---b" | tr '---' '-'
tr: unrecognised option '---'
try `tr --help' for more information

$ echo "a---b" | sed -e 's/---/-/g'
a-b
```